# prolems in converting from json formatted String to json object

Tags: blackberry, json

I have a web servlet that returns a json which is stored in my bb mobile app as string in json format....

Now I want to parse the string to extract values from it...
using

```
JSONObject jsobject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

returns an error:

> json must start with {

My JSON generated is in this format

```
[
   {"LASTNAME":"akre","FIRSTNAME":"swapnil"},
   {"LASTNAME":"akre","FIRSTNAME":"swapnil"},
   {"LASTNAME":"akre","FIRSTNAME":"swapnil"}
]
```

which is corect format as verified by jsonlint.com....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, json must start with `{` and end with `}` , what you can do is you put your json array in 
`{}`, so it will be parsed correctly. JsonLint parses the partial json as well thats why it is showing it as correct. You can try like following

yes, json must start with `{` and end with `}` , what you can do is you put your json array in `{}`, so it will be parsed correctly as jsonobject. JsonLint parses the partial json as well thats why it is showing it as correct

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "LASTNAME": "akre",
            "FIRSTNAME": "swapnil"
        },
        {
            "LASTNAME": "akre",
            "FIRSTNAME": "swapnil"
        },
        {
            "LASTNAME": "akre",
            "FIRSTNAME": "swapnil"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so this data also has the same problem...[link](http://docs.blackberry.com/sampledata.json)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using [this library](http://www.json.org/java/index.html).

Your JSON is an Array, so you'll have to use the `JSONArray` class to parse it